# How to install a linux distribution from rootfs using WLS?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'd like to install the latest Ubuntu 19.10 distribution following [Ubuntu guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL#Installing_Ubuntu_on_WSL_via_rootfs).

I downloaded and extracted the tar image and created "InstallLocation" - empty directory `c:\user\tmp\ubuntu`. And then following template `wsl --import <DistributionName> <InstallLocation> <FileName>` called:

```
C:\Users\user>wsl --import Ubuntu1910 "c:\user\tmp\ubuntu"  "C:\Users\user\tmp\eoan-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

However the `wsl` command is failing. How can be a new distro from rootfs image installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need quotes in your example. Unpacking the file too, it will be unpacked itself in the process. This is how it will work:

Command line options of [`wsl --import`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#import-a-new-distribution):

`wsl --import <Distribution Name> <InstallLocation> <FileName>`

Example:

`C:\Users\user>wsl --import Ubuntu1910 c:\user\tmp\ubuntu C:\Users\user\tmp\eoan-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz`

You won't see any answers after the command is run, but in a minute the files will be unpacked and a new registered distribution will appear in WLS.

Check it out by command: `wsl -l`

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/wsl-config